# How to group by func.week, year etc in Association proxy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two databases:

```
class AcUsers(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "ac_users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    b2c_customer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("b2c_customer.id", 
    ondelete="CASCADE"))
    ac_tests = db.relationship(
        "AcTests",
        back_populates="ac_user",
        uselist=False,
        lazy="joined",
    )
    last_test_submit_time = association_proxy("ac_tests", 
     "last_test_submit_time")
       
    class AcTests(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = "ac_tests"
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("ac_users.id"))
        ac_user = db.relationship(
            "AcUsers",
            back_populates="ac_tests",
            uselist=False,
            lazy="joined",
        )
        first_test_started_time = Column(DateTime)
        last_test_submit_time = Column(DateTime)
```

I have tried to query the database like this:

```
ac = (
db.session.query(
    func.count(AcUsers.id),
    func.week(AcUsers.last_test_submit_time),
    func.year(AcUsers.last_test_submit_time),
)
.filter(AcUsers.results_sent)
.filter(AcUsers.last_test_submit_time != None)
.all()
```

)

I got this error:

```
NotImplementedError: The association proxy can't be used as a plain column expression; it only works inside of a comparison expression
```

How the I get past this error in order to be able to use the group by week and year in order to know exactly the user for the present dispensation.

I have tried to get the daily, monthly, and yearly data by getting the data in the AcUsers and looping through it:

```
 ac_users = (
    db.session.query(AcUsers)
    .filter(AcUsers.results_sent)
    .filter(AcUsers.last_test_submit_time != None)
    .all()
)
```

daily:

```
  for user in ac_users:
        actual_date = user.last_test_submit_time.date()
        if actual_date not in daily_data:
            daily_data[actual_date] = 1
        else:
            daily_data[actual_date] += 1

    results_sent_daily = []
    for x, y in daily_data.items():
        results_sent_daily.append({"x": x, "y": y})
```

I did the same for the monthly and yearly.

How do i make the query use the grouping func into func.year, func.week, func.date etc.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [association proxy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#querying-with-association-proxies), the proxies are not meant for ORM querying aside from filtering.

The most simple thing to do is to craft a query using both models, specifying the join between them and the grouping fields.

```python
    ac = (
        s.dbs.query(
            func.count(AcUsers.id).label("count"),
            func.week(AcTests.last_test_submit_time).label("week"),
            func.year(AcTests.last_test_submit_time).label("year"),
        )
        .join(AcUsers.ac_tests)
        .group_by(
            func.week(AcTests.last_test_submit_time),
            func.year(AcTests.last_test_submit_time)
        )
        .filter(AcTests.last_test_submit_time != None)
        .all()
    )
```